# PHP concat a string into a variable x amount of times

Tags: php

I am trying to create a variable that has a string repeated x amount of times depending on what $tagtime3 =

This is what I have so far:

```
$tagtime = $length / $overlaylength;
        $tagtime3 = floor($tagtime);
        $stringtoloop = "' . $tagmp3 . '";
        for ($k = 0 ; $k < $tagtime3; $k++){ $finalstring = +.$stringtoloop; }
```

I think it could be done by pushing the string ' . $tagmp3 . ' into a variable within the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just `str_repeat($stringtoloop,$tagtime3);`?

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered [str_repeat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) this will repeat the string n amount of times:

```
$tagtime = $length / $overlaylength;
            $tagtime3 = floor($tagtime);
            $stringtoloop = "' . $tagmp3 . '";

            $test = str_repeat($stringtoloop, $tagtime3);
```